# JQGrid Function after inline edit

Tags: jqgrid, inline, edit

I can't seem to find the function that gets called after the editurl:"url" has completed.

I have:

```
colModel: [
                    { name: 'Email', index: 'Email', editable: true },
                    { name: 'ReferenceEmail', index: 'ReferenceEmail',hidden: true , editable: true, editrules: {edithidden:true}  },
                    { name: 'Title', index: 'Title',editable: true, edittype: "select", editoptions: { value: "Mr:Mr;Mrs:Mrs;Ms:Ms;Doctor:Doctor;Sir:Sir"} },
                    { name: 'Forename', index: 'Forename', editable: true },
                    { name: 'Surname', index: 'Surname', editable: true },
                    { name: 'Study_Manager', index: 'Study_Manager',editable: true, edittype: "select", editoptions: { value: "True:True;False:False"} }
                ],
        editurl: "/StudyManager/UserTable.aspx"
```

I need to set the ReferenceEmail = Email once edit has come back from the post to the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Byron, this should help:

[jqGrid: Why aren't the events that I defined for a grid edit firing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1381675/jqgrid-why-arent-the-events-that-i-defined-for-a-grid-edit-firing)

and on this reference page, you have *afterComplete* event which I think you should catch:

http://www.secondpersonplural.ca/jqgriddocs/_2eb0gp5ym.htm

cheers

Answer (score 1):

I'm being an idiot:

```
$("#UserGrid").jqGrid('editRow', id, true, oneditfunc, reload);
```

then set

```
Function reload(rowid,result)
{
}
```